# Integrating Phoenix compiler framework with Eclipse for a JAVA class

Tags: java, compiler-construction, eclipse-juno

I want to use the methods of the "Graph" class from the Phx.Graphs Namespace of the Phoenix compiler framework (by Microsoft) in the JAVA class that I built on Eclipse JUNO. Can someone help me figure out as to how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awryt. So basically I can't really use those methods from the framework, because the tools (of and by Phoenix) are dead AFAIK. I've figured out that I'd implement the methods in my way using the ZEST package.
Thanks to whoever saw the post but couldn't help! :)